# NoClassDefFound Error, how to solve it?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have `GreetingClient` class here:

`C:\Users\khoy\Desktop\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\src\Networking`

When i try it in command line by typing `java GreetingClient` (after javac GreetingClient.java), it generates the error (as seen in the screen shot below):

[image]

Comment: is your Class in some package ?

Comment: Note how it says `wrong name: ...`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, it is is `Networking` package

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it says `Wrong name: Networking/GreetingClient`, `Networking` is my package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go up one level and execute `java Networking.GreetingClient`

---

**Note**

- Your package naming doesn't match convention

**See**

- [package naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)
- [java package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/)

Comment: Not work, Same result.

Comment: did you do _go up one_